# sql logical A and (B or C)

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to write sql code(using PROC SQL in SAS)  using the logical

A and (B or C)

Where A is of the form (A1 AND A_2 AND A_3 ... A_n) so in other words it long

since the AND operator evaluates first, in sql code, I cant write it as

```
A AND (B or C)
```

because the parentheses does have any effect I would get `A AND B OR C`

My question is do I have to write it as:

```
(A and B) or (A and C)
```

this would require  to write a long (logical) expression `A` two times.

Comment: Who told you parentheses don't have any effect?

Comment: Personally, I always use parens when using OR or any mathematical operations that extend beyond a single operation for clarity's sake even if it doesn't change the order of evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this should work if `B` and `C` have only one clause:

```
A and (B or C)
```

But, we are not currently suffering a shortage of parentheses in the world, so you can use more:

```
( A ) and ( ( B ) or ( C ) )
```

Just wrap each logic condition (no matter how long) in parentheses.